# ODBC connection to SQL Server through firewall

Tags: firewall, odbc

**The Status Quo:**

There's a SQL Server (2005) database. On the same network, There's a user who connects a Visual FoxPro instance to said database via ODBC. This works, the user is happy, and everything is hunky dory.

**Looming on the horizon:**

The SS database is going to move to another network. There will be a firewall between it & the VFP user. This user *does* have access through the firewall via VPN, and a SQL account in the relocated database (**no** domain account on the new network).

**The Question:**

Will we be able to construct an ODBC connection string such that the VFP user can still use the SS back end? Anything special we need to do when setting it up? Anything special the user needs to do to connect?

If this belongs on SO rather than SF, let me know & I'll take it over there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to construct an ODBC connection string such that the VFP user can still use the SS back end.  No, nothing special is needed to set it up.

When he/she VPNs into the network the Sql Server will appear on the same network as the VFP user.  Simply connect as normal.

Comment: Thanks. I'll come back and Accept your answer as soon as I've been able to prove it in my own environment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup, the SQL Server and the VPN user might not end up on the same network, and the firewall would probably block any broadcast regarding computer-names etc (NetBIOS).

Unless you have an AD-server that act as DNS, you might need to use IP-addressing instead of computer name (NetBIOS) in order to connect to the SQL Server, which might be a change you need to provide to the connection-string.

Answer (score 0):

If there some firewall rules, you must allow 1433 port for default instance SQL, if you have named instanse you must look in Configuration Manager which dynamic ports uses in TCP/IP and allow this port on firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article I wrote that goes into good detail about Sql Server instances and the ports that need to be opened up to allow remote access.

http://mattslay.com/opening-up-sql-server-to-allow-remote-connections/